# Delete MySQL information in table using Cron jobs

Tags: php, mysql, cron, sql-delete

I am using cPanel, trying to use cron jobs to delete all data in a table, but when I went to cron jobs in cPanel, I got an error when I put in the following:

```
DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE
```

I checked my email for completion of the cron job and received the following message:

```
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
/bin/sh: -c: line 0: `DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 
MINUTE'
```

I have been researching this issue for the last 2 hours and I haven't found any information on how to run a cron job from cPanel to delete all info in a table.

The database is named tragicco_patron and the table is patron_joined.  Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to invoke CLI mysql-client like this:

```
0 23 * * * * root /usr/bin/mysql -e "USE mydatabase; DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;"
```

Comment: 0 23 * * * * root /usr/bin/mysql -e "USE tragicco_patron; DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;"

This is what I used, however the cron does not work at all now.
I am set to receive emails from the cron daemon, and I set this to run every minute, not it didn't happen.

Comment: After checking my spam folder, it looks like it worked, however this happened.

/bin/sh: 0: command not found

Hmm...what is missing here?

Comment: 0 23 * * * * /usr/bin/mysql --host=localhost --user=tragicco_user --password=password database -e "DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;"

I tried this later on, and this didn't work either.

Comment: /usr/bin/mysql --host=localhost --user=tragicco_user --password=password tragicco_patron -e "DELETE FROM patron_joined WHERE uid < NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MINUTE;"

That did the trick, you got me on the right path.  Thanks!