# trigger delete row mysql

Tags: mysql, triggers

How can I create a trigger that will automatically delete a row when it comes to a certain date.
I have the following table:

```html
+----+-------+------------+
| ID |  NAME |   ACTIVE   |
+----+-------+------------+
| 1  | Name1 | 31.03.2018 |
| 2  | Name2 | 14.04.2018 |
| 3  | Name3 | 31.03.2018 |
+----+-------+------------+
```

When it comes to March 31, 2018, the rows associated with this date to be automatically deleted.

Thank you!

Comment: Not possible. You can however write a program that runs everyday and deletes such rows. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23922940/delete-mysql-information-in-table-using-cron-jobs

Comment: You cannot action the table which invoked the trigger. You could instead create an event to do this.https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/event-scheduler.html